# Why this Ajax request returns as an error?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Here's my problem : I make an ajax request to a WordPress PHP function. Strange thing is : this response is returned as an error.

But in the error log, the responseText is the requested data (JSON as a string), the status is 200 and statusText is "OK".

Here's the request :

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: { action:'my_wp_function',username: settings.username, list: settings.list, hashtag: settings.hashtag, count: settings.count, exclude_replies: settings.hideReplies, lastID:settings.lastID  }
      }).done(function( res ) {

      }).error(function(err) { console.log(err); }); // err.responseText = the requested data ...
```

S if all is OK, why is this request detected as if an error has occurred ?

EDIT, here's the PHP I request:

```
<?php

require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); 
require_once('config.php');


if (CONSUMER_KEY === '' || CONSUMER_SECRET === '' || CONSUMER_KEY === 'CONSUMER_KEY_HERE' || CONSUMER_SECRET === 'CONSUMER_SECRET_HERE') {
    echo 'You need a consumer key and secret keys. Get one from <a href="https://dev.twitter.com/apps">dev.twitter.com/apps</a>';

    exit;
}

$username = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$number = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'count', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$exclude_replies = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'exclude_replies', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$list_slug = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'list_slug', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$hashtag = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'hashtag', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$lastID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'lastID', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

if(CACHE_ENABLED) {
    // Generate cache key from query data
    $cache_key = md5(
        var_export(array($username, $number, $exclude_replies, $list_slug, $hashtag), true) . HASH_SALT
    );

    $cache_path  = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/';
    foreach (glob($cache_path . '*') as $file) {
        if (filemtime($file) < time() - CACHE_LIFETIME) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    if(file_exists($cache_path . $cache_key)) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        echo file_get_contents($cache_path . $cache_key);
        exit;
    }
}


function getConnectionWithToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_secret)
{
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_secret);

    return $connection;
}

// Connect
$connection = getConnectionWithToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);

// Get Tweets
if (!empty($list_slug)) {
  $params = array(
      'owner_screen_name' => $username,
      'slug' => $list_slug,
      'per_page' => $number
  );

  $url = '/lists/statuses';
} 

else if($hashtag) {
  if($lastID){
    $params = array(
      'max_id' => $lastID,
      'count' => 100,
      'q' => '#'.$hashtag.' filter:images',
      'include_entities' => true

  );

  }
  else {
    $params = array(
      'count' => 100,
      'q' => '#'.$hashtag.' filter:images',
      'include_entities' => true

  );
  }


  $url = '/search/tweets';
} else {
  $params = array(
      'count' => $number,
      'exclude_replies' => $exclude_replies,
      'screen_name' => $username
  );

  $url = '/statuses/user_timeline';
}

// $rawTweets = $connection->get($url, $params);
// $tweets = array();
$tweets = $connection->get($url, $params);



// Return JSON Object
header('Content-Type: application/json');


$tweets = json_encode( $tweets);

if(CACHE_ENABLED) file_put_contents($cache_path . $cache_key, $tweets);

echo $tweets;
```

Comment: What does the console say exactly?

Comment: could you show me the part of your php code, and make next several things, remove dataType from request, build up data which you wanna send before request and path object to data opton, like this : data: object, in answer be sure that u parse your json and in php use json_encode

Comment: Yes, the PHP code returns (echo) a json vairable (json_encode). I tried without dataType: it's the same (returns as an error).

Comment: Could you copy/paste the console output, you can replace any private data with asterisks.

Comment: I pasted the console output : I remove lot of data from responseText (as it was too big to SO : note that it's a valid JSON array of objects).

Comment: I get it : I forgot to die(); my WP function, so it returned : "{...objects...}0" So it can't be successfull.

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
$.ajax({
        url : _url,
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "JSON",
        error : function(){
            console.log("Cannot bring the core fields");
        },
        success : function (response){
                  console.info( response );
});
```

Comment: It's the same code as I posted. What should work now ?